# Gulp error: The following tasks did not complete: Async Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sass, gulp

I am kind of new to gulp and I am getting this error after updating gulp-sass to 5.0. I tried different thing from internet but didn't get it to work.

Gulp version : 4.0.0
Gulp sass : 5.0.0
sass : 1.38.1

[image]

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
var sourcemaps    = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var mode          = require('gulp-mode')();
var browserSync   = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass          = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
var $             = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var autoprefixer  = require('autoprefixer');
var isProduction = mode.production();

var sassPaths = [
//   'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss',
//   'node_modules/motion-ui/src'
];


function sass() {
  return gulp.src('assets/sass/theme.scss')
    .pipe(mode.development(sourcemaps.init()))
    .pipe($.sass.sync(({
      includePaths: sassPaths,
      outputStyle: 'compressed' // if css compressed **file size**
    })).on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.postcss([
      autoprefixer({ overrideBrowserslist: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 9'] })
    ]))
    .pipe(mode.development(sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
};

function serve() {
    browserSync.init({
      server: "./"
    });
  gulp.watch("assets/sass/**/*.{scss,sass}", sass);
  gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

gulp.task('sass', sass);
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('sass', serve));
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass', serve));

if( isProduction ){
  gulp.task('default', gulp.series(sass));
}
```

Comment: No one uses gulp anymore since 2014 ;)

Comment: @Dominic 1.3M per week .

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issue:

1. Don't name your task `sass` and your `require` object also `sass`.  Pick a different name for one of them.
2. This is strange:

```js
gulp.task('sass', sass);
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('sass', serve));
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass', serve));
```

All you need is

```
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series(sass2, serve));
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(sass2, serve));
```

Just use your task names, here I just renamed it to `sass2`, no need to refer to them as strings.

Also your `serve` is no different than your `default` task...